# Can I make and receive phone calls using a tablet with a SIM card slot in it?

Tags: tablet, calls

I have an Android tablet without telephony capabilities. I can put in a SIM card. When somebody calls my SIM card number (mobile number), can I receive this call? What application do I need?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens? Some Android tablet builds actually have the phone app installed.

Comment: What tablet do you have? (Ok, I see from the duplicate question... Huawei MediaPad ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you usually can't receive calls with an tablet which doesn't provide this functionality. The SIM card slot is only for mobile data communication and there is no way that you just download an App which enables GSM phone functionality (AFAIK).

You can use VoIP though.

Comment: I have GSM in my phone spec.

Comment: Hmm, can some ROM be flashed which has telephony support?

Comment: @user14416 GSM means 2G network

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a [Huawei MediaPad](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/productFeatures.do?pinfoId=3135&directoryId=5011&treeId=3290&tab=0) as mentioned in [your other/duplicate thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22028/mobile-phone-calls-on-huawei-mediapad). Then the Huawei's own website states in the FAQ section:

> **Can I make phone calls using MediaPad?**
>
> Android 3.2 (Honeycomb) does not provide a function to make calls, but
>   you can download and install applications from Hispace to make phone
>   calls. Note:
>
> - As determined by operators' rate plans, most systems do not support voice calls even with calling applications installed. With the
>     universal MediaPad version, calling is supported.
> - Calling is not a default function of Android 3.2 (Honeycomb). Downloading and installing applications are users' personal behaviors.
> - Internet telephony is supported.
> - Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) supports all calling functions.

Source:
http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/faq.do?method=getFaqInfo&questionId=7564